# Cannot enter CoffeeScript for loop

Tags: for-loop, foreach, scope, coffeescript, range

Why isn't my code hitting the line that contains the `alert`?

```
window.Game = class Game
  constructor: ->
    rows: 22
    columns: 10
    board: []

createBoard: ->                                                                                                                                                                                           
  # Some code here...
  for x in [0...@columns]
    alert("THIS IS HERE")
  # More code down here...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because `@columns` is `undefined`.

Your constructor:

```
constructor: ->
  rows: 22
  columns: 10
  board: []
```

simply creates an object and throws it away, it is the same as this:

```
constructor: ->
  o = {
    rows: 22
    columns: 10
    board: []
  }
  return
```

So no instance variables are set and your constructor doesn't do much at all. Perhaps you meant to say:

```
constructor: ->
  @rows = 22
  @columns = 10
  @board = []
```

or possibly:

```
constructor: (@rows = 22, @columns = 10, @board = [ ]) ->
```

I'm assuming that your `createBoard` method is actually indented one level so that it is a method in your `Game` class.